# How to see html result built with reactjs

Tags: html, reactjs, browser, frontend, output

I'm building reactjs app. I want to grab full html output but when I try to `view page source` I see only template from `index.html`. How can I see HTML built by the app?

I believe it is possible because I can see HTML tree in developer tools in Elements tab, but I need it in plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome one can use Developer tools to achieve this. Go to `Elements` and in context menu choose `Edit as HTML`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**There is no way to see `view page source` in react js project .**

....
But
You can use React Developer Tools browser extension. This will allow you to see the Component Tree of any React application. Also, you can inspect props and state of each component with it. But still, you won't be able to see the source code of Component after a production build.

Comment: Well, you can view the minified code for the bundles that were delivered, but without the source maps it's a bit more tedious to read through.

Comment: what do you mean with _There is no way to see `view page source` in react js project_? I don't want to see `view page source`, I want to see the source of what I see on the screen.

Comment: @Yola Are you thinking of the DOM inspector? That's what's on the screen. You can view the page source to view the HTML of the page.